# lein figwheel vs lein cljsbuild auto

Tags: clojurescript, figwheel, cljsbuild

What is the difference between lein figwheel and lein cljsbuild auto because I believe that they are both used to compile clojurescript.

Also is there any benefit to using one over the other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Figwheel

They are both lein plugins but Figwheel not only compiles cljs into javascript but it also features *hot loading* which allows interactive programming, actually Figwheel uses cljsbuild for compiling cljs.

You can create a figwheel app using:

```
lein new figwheel app
```

If you run:

```
lein figwheel
```

Figwheel will create a server process by default on port 3449, you can connect your browser to `localhost:3449` and when you change your source code you'll see that Figwheel compiles the code and hotloads the new compiled javascript into your browser (using websockets).

### Cljsbuild

Cljsbuild is a plugin for facilitating compiling (or transpiling) cljs into javascript, it can do automatically (`auto`) by watching to changes in the source files or you can use `once` to build js once, that's it.

Otherwise without cljsbuild you should use something like:

```
java -cp cljs.jar:src clojure.main build.clj
```

Where `cljs.jar` is the ClojureScript compiler and `build.clj` is the build configuration for a project.

### Info

Check the [ClojureScript getting started page](http://clojurescript.org/guides/quick-start), will give you some insight on how the building process works.

Also check how to use [Figwheel with LightTable](https://github.com/bhauman/lein-figwheel/wiki/Running-figwheel-with-LightTable), which is a nice match, a more advanced approach could be using CIDER on emacs, but the configuration can be cumbersome at first.

*Also is there any benefit to using one over the other?*

They are different tools, Fighweel *wraps* cljsbuild, so I would use Figwheel when I can.