# Clojurescript's browser REPL on Windows

Tags: browser, windows-7-x64, clojurescript, read-eval-print-loop

Following the Quick Start wiki page of ClojureScript, I'm trying to have the REPL inside Chrome web browser (as seen there: https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Quick-Start#browser-repl)

I'm running on Windows and I'm skipping the "brew rlwrap" part because I'm clueless about what it should mean to a Windows user and the link to rlwrap is broken.

When I run the command `java -cp "cljs.jar;src" clojure.main repl.clj` in the console then open "http://localhost:9000/" on the browser, I can see java app (cls.jar) crashes.

> Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException:
>   Illegal/unsupported escap e sequence near index 7 g:\Dev\Clojurescript
>          ^
>           at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.regex.Pattern.escape(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.regex.Pattern.atom(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.regex.Pattern.(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
>           at cljs.repl.browser$send_static.invokeStatic(browser.clj:108)
>           at cljs.repl.browser$send_static.invoke(browser.clj:92)
>           at cljs.repl.server$dispatch_request.invokeStatic(server.clj:157)
>           at cljs.repl.server$handle_connection.invokeStatic(server.clj:164)
>           at cljs.repl.server$server_loop$fn__5494.invoke(server.clj:175)
>           at clojure.core$binding_conveyor_fn$fn__4676.invoke(core.clj:1938)
>           at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use directly the cljs.jar file, use [Leiningen](http://leiningen.org/) with a minimal template like [mies](https://github.com/swannodette/mies), you have to install Leiningen first, download this [script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/technomancy/leiningen/stable/bin/lein.bat) for windows and run it.

Then use:

```
lein new mies myapp
```

This will create a ClojureScript project with all the necessary scripts.

Open the `core.cljs` file and uncomment these lines:

```
(defonce conn
  (repl/connect "http://localhost:9000/repl"))
```

To run the browser repl (executing inside the `myapp` folder).

```
scripts\brepl.bat
```

This will compile and run the browser repl, when the process is complete connect Google Chrome to `localhost:9000`, then the repl should go online.

When you feel sure enough, for a more advanced approach check [figwheel](https://github.com/swannodette/mies), which gives you advanced features, like autobuild and hotswapping.

Check also my other answer about the [differences between cljsbuild and figwheel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40738366/lein-figwheel-vs-lein-cljsbuild-auto/40741397#40741397).